# How to extract numbers and mathematical operator from a complex mathematical captcha

Tags: java, captcha, python-tesseract

I want to use Python to automate access to a web site that uses such captcha. I tried to use pytesseract but I didn't have any results.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a CAPTCHA ("Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart") is exactly to be extremely difficult for machines to extract the text or the visual elements, while a "normal" human being should not have any trouble.

There are several ways that you can employ to bypass a CAPTCHA, however, keep in mind that just a little evolution in the CAPTCHA itself could result in significant additional difficulty in bypassing it.

The CAPTCHA you are trying to read cannot be read with a standard OCR, otherwise the purpose itself of a CAPTCHA would be defeated. Furthermore, it is asking to perform a mathematical operation on the extracted data. The operation itself could be changed at any time.

At the beginning, several sites hosted the solution of their CAPTCHA in the page itself, or in the address of the image. Nowadays, this is extremely rare.

To my knowledge, the most effective way to solve these kind of CAPTCHAs is to rely on network of humans that do the job. I am not sure if links to these networks can be posted here in SO, however a simple Google search does the job.

Typically the network has a client to submit the image, and you get back the text of the CAPTCHA. Depending on the network you earn credits for solving and lose them for asking CAPTCHAs.

This can be automated. Just remember, that modern CAPTCHAs require user interaction with the CAPTCHA itself, under the form of clicks and drag&drops, therefore these networks would be ineffective in those cases.